# Dynamically Appending Partial View with Scripts in jQuery: Handling 'Identifier Already Declared' Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm encountering an issue while dynamically appending a partial view containing scripts using jQuery. The partial view includes scripts declared with `const` that result in an "Identifier Already Declared" error when the partial view is appended more than once.

I'm dynamically loading a partial view with the following code:

```
$('#dv_partialBody').empty().append('my partial viewer');
```

The partial view contains scripts that are dynamically added to the main document, such as:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tagsinput.js?t=" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tagsinput.js")).ToString()))"></script>
<script>
    var refFieldDataList = [], refFieldDataList = [];
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Areas/Document/Views/Document/_DocProDMSFolderStructure.js?t=" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Areas/Document/Views/Document/_DocProDMSFolderStructure.js")).ToString()))"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/commonscript/CommonDocumentsViewJS.js?t=" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Scripts/commonscript/CommonDocumentsViewJS.js")).ToString()))"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/moment.min.js?t=" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Scripts/moment.min.js")).ToString()))"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/common/js/JqueryUIAutoCompleteDropdownlist.js?t=" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Resources/common/js/JqueryUIAutoCompleteDropdownlist.js")).ToString()))"></script>
```

When I reload the partial view by emptying the div and appending it again, I face an "Identifier Already Declared" error due to `const` declarations within the scripts.

How can I efficiently handle the "Identifier Already Declared" error when dynamically appending a partial view with scripts? Is there a recommended way to remove or refresh the scripts to avoid conflicts?

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use global const variables.  Use modules or namespaces.   Alternatively (or as well...) load all the required scripts in the main page, not in the partial.   Yes, you might load scripts that you may not use, but also means you're not double-loading scripts (which is likely worse) and saves the issue you have here.